# How do I validate text entry to include only numbers?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to obligate the person who is using my program to enter only numbers in the text label in c#. How can i do that?
example : 
number of equations : (he should only enter a number)

This code to obligate him to enter a number between `2` and `10` but i need a code for letters

```
if (int.Parse(txt1.Text) < 2 || int.Parse(txt1.Text) > 10)
   {
     l6.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     l6.Text = "Svp choisir un nombre entre 2 et 10 ... Soyez Logique!";
   }
```

Comment: TryParse won't throw an exception if the user enters a letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (txt1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
{
    // Parse the value only once as it can be quite performance expensive.
    Int32 value = Int32.Parse(txt1.Text)

    if ((value >= 2) && (value <= 10))
    {
        l6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        l6.Text = "Svp choisir un nombre entre 2 et 10 ... Soyez Logique!";

        // Clear the text...
        txt1.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        // Your code here...
    }
}
```

But, IMHO, TryParse is even better as it can handle bad string formats in a better way:

```
if (txt1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
{
    Int32 value;

    if (!Int32.TryParse(txt1.Text, out value))
    {
        l6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        l6.Text = "Svp choisir un nombre entre 2 et 10 ... Soyez Logique!";

        // Clear the text...
        txt1.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        // Your code here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put this (or a variation of this, according to what you want to let the user to enter) in the textbox keypress event, so basically you will manage key presses in this textbox..
Add System.Media library to use the beep if the user enters wrong key, or remove it from the code...

```
        if ((e.KeyChar >= '0') && (e.KeyChar <= '9') && (txt1.Text.Length < 10))
        {

        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == 0x08)
        {
            //BACKSPACE CHAR
        }
        else if (txt1.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            //IF TEXT SELECTED -> LET IT OVERRIDE
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What GUI do you use?
Using Winforms there are two ways that come to mind:

1. I recommend: Use a numericUpDown Control instead of a textBox. This way the user can only enter numbers and has nice Up/Down arrows to change the value. Plus you get handling of cursor keys.
2. Implement an [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the various methods to insert text in a textbox to avoid non number chars is not an easy task and more often than not it fails somewhere. For example what about text pasted from the clipboard?, what about Backspace, Delete, Left, Right arrows keys?.

In my opinion it is better to follow a different approach.
Use the Validating event and let the user type or paste whatever he wants. At the validation event do you checks and advise the user or add a special errorProvider to signal the error:

```
    private void l6_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        int isNumber = 0;
        if (l6.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(l6.Text, out isNumber))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                errorProvider1.SetError(l6, "Svp choisir un nombre entre 2 et 10 ...";);
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(l6, "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```